# What could cause a DynamoDB table scan to return no data and yet no error either?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have two small DynamoDB tables, one having 41 items with 6 attributes each and one having 40 items with 2 attributes each. Both tables are indexed with primary and secondary sort keys.

A scan of the larger one, *FHCClassSchedule*, returns the correct entire table contents. A scan of the smaller, *FHCRoomCounts*, returns no data *and* no error either. The [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) says that if the scan returns no data it will return an error. But that's (seemingly) not what's happening.

I've seen the question [Scan DynamoDB table is not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641296/scan-dynamodb-table-is-not-returning-data), but his situation was materially different from mine. His table was large and unindexed. He was making but one scan request when multiple requests were required because the table exceeded the 1MB limit per request. That's not the situation with me.

The relevant code is:

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var err;
var data;
var counts;
var paramsClassSchedule = {
                           TableName: 'FHCClassSchedule'
                          };
var paramsRoomCounts = {
                          TableName: 'FHCRoomCounts'
                       };
dynamodb.scan(paramsRoomCounts, function( err, counts ) {
  if( err ) {console.log('error @ .scan paramsRoomCounts, err == ', err);}

});
dynamodb.scan( paramsClassSchedule, function( err, data){
    if (err) { console.log('error @ .scan paramsClassSchedule, err == ', err); }
        else {
               console.log('(data, counts) : (', data, counts, ')');
               // other code processing counts & data
             }
```

The console.log shows `data` is an object having the correct content in it. But `counts` remains `undefined`, yet there is no error returned. It's as if the scan request was just not executed.

I've examined all the various settings (Overview, Items, Metrics, Alarms, ...) for each table and they are the same. I can see nothing in these settings about the *FHCRoomCounts* table to distinguish it from the *FHCClassSchedule* table.

So, I'm at a loss.

**Edit:**
I'd give you a snippet, but to make it connect to Amazon Web Services, I'd have to put my access key and 'secret' access key in the snippet. Since, with them, one would have unfettered access to my account, I'm disinclined to do that. I'd use Amazon Cognito, but I haven't (yet) mastered it.

***Update***
This was an important lesson for me in variable scope.

The variables `counts` and `data` "exist" within the confines of the dynamodb.scan anonymous callback functions. The are function scoped. I was accessing them outside the scope and therefore they were `undefined`.

I needed to put the JavaScript that accesses and processes them inside the *nested* scans. The answer is to nest the two scans one within the other's callback function, and then to nest the js that processes the variables returned by the callbacks inside the innermost nested scan.

The correct code is:

```
function init() {

  dynamodb.scan(paramsRoomCounts, function( err, counts ) {
   if( err ) {console.log('error @ .scan paramsRoomCounts, err == ',    err);}

    dynamodb.scan( paramsClassSchedule, function( err, data){
      if (err) { console.log('error @ .scan paramsClassSchedule, err == ', err); }
      else {
             console.log('(data, counts) : (', data, counts, ')');
             // further js processing the data and counts variables

           }
    });  // end def callback & scan of paramsClassSchedule
  });  //  end def callback & scan of paramsRoomCounts
}  // end def function init()
```

Now, the console.log inside the nested `else` block will log the correct `data` and `counts` content. The remaining code inside the `else` block will work as expected.

Many thanks to the great customer support guys at AWS for their dedication to helping me learn this lesson.

Comment: Those `.scan()` calls are *asynchronous*. The callback functions will be invoked when the operation completes, but the `.scan()` call itself returns immediately.

Comment: @Pointy I'm a novice with this, and a little dense too. I'm afraid I don't see how that helps me solve (or prevent) the problem. Can you elaborate for me?

Comment: It's hard to provide much help because you've left out a lot of code. One possible issue is that the `counts` variable is not initialized (to 0, if it really is a "count"). It's not clear where in your code you expect `counts` to be defined. If it's *inside* the `.scan()` callback, that's fine; if it's *outside*, then that's a problem too.

Comment: @Pointy The vars counts & data are defined and assigned values by the callback functions. All the rest of the code just uses their contents to fill out a table on the web page. These few lines encompass the whole problem. One .scan call works, the other doesn't. I'm checking out your idea about asynchronicity with the AWS tech support guy. He seems stymied too. If you've any other thoughts, I'd sure be glad of them. If you care to, you can see the page at [this page](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-class-schedule-2019).

Comment: @Pointy The answer is that the two variables are function scoped and I was accessing them outside the scope of the callback function. I updated the Q with an explanation and the correct code. Thanks for your time and interest. Really. I appreciated it.